# How can I optimise this code?

Tags: excel, performance, vba

Everytime, when cell value (1,2) changes it will copy that value and the value of cell (10,19) and paste it in column A & B respectively
My Excel VBA makes Excel hang when the value of cell (1,2) changes:

```
Dim a As Variant

Dim j As Integer
Dim b As Variant
Dim l As Integer




Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Cells(j + 3, 1).Value = Cells(j + 2, 1).Value Then
          j = j
          Else
          j = j + 1

        End If

  If l < j Then
b = Cells(10, 19).Value
 Cells(j + 1, 2).Value = b

End If
l = j
a = Cells(1, 2).Value
Cells(j + 3, 1).Value = a


End Sub

Private Sub Combobox1_Change()
 Cells(1, 2) = Combobox1.Value

End Sub
```

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: What is `j` supposed to be? Every time you change a cell value the code is kicking in.  And it is kicking in constantly, because you are changing cell values in the code.

Comment: This is better put in codereview http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This would probably work better as a sub that gets called from the combobox1_change.  Put a loop in that works through all the desired cells.

Comment: Damn... Pretty tough to divine/guess what you are trying to do with this... Please edit your question to include more details!

Comment: Well everytime, when cell value (1,2) changes it will copy that value and the value of cell (10,19) and paste it in column A & B respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your formatting makes it difficult to read.
Second, you are not disabling events when changing values, causing an eventual stack overflow or out of memory error, which will slow excel down.

Formatted and improved code:

```
Dim a 
Dim j As Integer
Dim b 
Dim l As Integer

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, "A:A") Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'don't run unless change in column A

Application.EnableEvents = False 'stop executing this code until we are done
If Cells(j + 3, 1).Value = Cells(j + 2, 1).Value Then
    j = j
Else
    j = j + 1
End If

If l < j Then
    b = Cells(10, 19).Value
    Cells(j + 1, 2).Value = b
End If

l = j
a = Cells(1, 2).Value
Cells(j + 3, 1).Value = a
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub Combobox1_Change()
Cells(1, 2) = Combobox1.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: changed  If Intersect(Target, "A:A") to If Intersect(Target, range("A:A")) and defined dim a & b as variant the code worked for me thanks alot sir for timely reply.